# Why does it skip array index 0?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I came across this computer science problem and it wasn't working out the way I was writing it down. This is the code:

```
int[][]grid = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8,9},{10}};

    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++)
            grid[j][i] = grid[i][j];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grid[1]));
```

It should change grid[0] to {1, 5, 8, 10} but instead it does nothing to it. Why does it skip over that one? Shouldn't `i` start out as 0 so the second for loop should start with `grid[0][0] = grid[0][0]` then `grid[1][0] = grid[0][1]`?

Comment: To change grid[0] to {1,5,8,10} you should do `grid[i][j] = grid[j][i];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're changing the initial variable (grid) on each iteration, put the output into a separate variable and then print that.

Explanation:

```
grid = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7},{8,9},{10}};
```

After the first sub loop (looping j)

```
grid = {{1,2,3,4},{2,6,7},{3,9},{4}};
```

Then when it performs the subsequent i loops, you can see it puts the numbers back where they were. If you start with an empty array as your output variable, you will avoid this problem.

Comment: obviously if required for any reason, after the processing of the loops is complete, you can assign the output variable content back into the input variable (grid)